# Why can't I find the IDE-inserted data in terminal mode?

Tags: mongodb, go, goland, mongo-go

I was trying to insert data through Goland IDE in MongoDB. Though the connection is right and in the IDE output I got the ObjectID, I still cannot see the results from terminal directly. It seems that the database records a new document without any information...

OSX, MongoDB is at default setting. Driver is 'go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver' and the connection is right. Goland is at 2019.2.2

```
// go

type Student struct {
    name string
    sex string
}

newStu := Student{
    name: "Alice",
    sex: "Female",
}

collection := client.Database("mgo_1").Collection("student")

insertResult, err := collection.InsertOne(context.TODO(), newStu)

if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
    }

fmt.Println(insertResult.InsertedID)
```

This is the insertion part, which I followed the guide on [mongodb.com](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial)

```
> db.student.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d82d826f5e2f29823900275"), "name" : "Michael", "sex" : "Male" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d82d845b8db68b150894f5a") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d82dc2952c638d0970e9356") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d82dcde8cf407b2fb5649e7") }
```

This is the result I query in another terminal. Except the first one which has some content, the other three are what I tried to insert to the database through Goland for three times.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]. We know how to insert a single document. What I for my part can not understand how 4 documents show up after a single insert... I assume there is some code missing... ;)

Answer (score 0):

So your struct looks like this:

```
type Student struct {
    name string
    sex string
}
```

The `name` and `sex` fields don't begin with capitals so they're not exported and thus not visible to reflection. `InsertOne` undoubtedly uses reflection to figure out what's in `newStu` but the `Student` struct has no exported fields so `InsertOne` can't see any fields in `newStu` at all.

If you fix your struct to have exported fields:

```
type Student struct {
    Name string
    Sex string
}
```

then `InsertOne` will be able to figure out what's in it. The MongoDB interface should figure out the mapping from `Name` (Go) to `name` (MongoDB) and `Sex` to `sex` on its own.